# How do I make Linux terminal shell out of these instructions?

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, gdb, raspbian, atmel

I have been trying to make a .sh script using the instructions to run on the Raspberry Pi for the Atmel ATSAMD51G19A:

---

1. Launch openocd in a new terminal window:

`sudo openocd -f openocdcfg.cfg`

OpenOCD should stay running if it successfully connected to the device.

2. In a second terminal window, run the following:

`gdb-multiarch AtmelStart.elf`

3. Type these within gdb (say yes when prompted):

```
target remote :3333
lo 
file User.elf
lo
mon reset
```

The display device should now be running the ncdisplay code.

---

Now I have no issues flashing the firmware onto the Atmel MCU. I only have issues when creating part 3 of the .sh script.  So far, here is what my script looks like for part 3

```
(gdb) -ex target remote :3333
(gdb) -ex lo
(gdb) -ex file User.elf
(gdb) -ex y
(gdb) -ex y
(gdb) -ex lo
(gdb) -ex mon reset
(gdb) -ex q
```

**None of the commands listed above will execute within gdb in terminal**.  I'm also unsure how to include 'y' for 'yes' within gdb when making a script.  The terminal just stays idle waiting for the user to type a command.

I am still learning a lot about Linux and Debian/Ubuntu.  In addition, this is the first time I have ever worked with gdb.  Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDB takes a `-x` command line argument that allows you to pass in a set of commands to run, see https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/File-Options.html#File-Options for more details.

So you can place your GDB commands into a separate file (lets call it `cmd.gdb`) and then do `gdb-multiarch -x cmd.gdb AtmelStart.elf`.

If GDB is processing commands from a command file then it will assume `yes` in answer to the yes/no prompts, so GDB will not stop.

If you do want to stick to using `-ex` then you can try adding this command to the start of your list `-ex 'set confirm off'` this should stop GDB asking you yes/no questions.

Comment: Hello Andrew,

Thank you so much for the help! It now works.  In the future, I'll consider the link you put in your answer.

Thank you for your time,
P Keshavarzi